# reading file , checkBox value on the server side in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, servlets, gwt2, formpanel

My problem is [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9634001/1046176)

i have to Send the textBox.value and file.
I am using FormPanel to do so.

I can retrive file but the value of checkBox is not retrived.

How to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a name on your checkbox and in your servlet retrieve the value with `request.getParameter(name)` where the name matches the one of your checkbox.