# Liferay: How to make enctype="multipart/form-data" and method="post" work together?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, liferay

I'm developing a web app using liferay portal server 6.2

JSP code -

```
    <form id="mainForm" action="<portlet:actionURL/>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type="hidden" id="varImport" name="varImport"/>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="uploadFile">
        <p>Please upload a file</p>
        <div id="inputFileDiv">
            <input type="file" name="uploadFile" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" onClick="import()" value="IMPORT" />
    </form>

    <script>
        function import() {
            console.log("importing");
            document.getElementById("varImport").value = "IMPORTFILE";
            document.getElementById("mainForm").submit();
        }
    </script>
```

Servlet code -

```
@Override
    public void processAction(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) throws PortletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("myPortlet.processAction() >> " + request.getParameter("varImport"));

    //... rest of the code.  
}
```

If I remove **enctype** from jsp form, I get the value of varImport in my servlet.

But if i keep it, it returns null.

What am i missing?

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536947/passing-parameters-along-with-a-multipart-form-data-upload-form-java-http-post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil;
UploadPortletRequest uploadRequest = PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(request);
System.out.println("myPortlet.processAction() >> " + uploadRequest.getParameter("varImport"));
```