# How to send additional parameter when POSTing through FormPanel?

Tags: java, gwt

I have a client-side GWT-FormPanel, which has an import file functionality. I want to pass cookie along with the form to the action on the server-side.

I tried this method:  [Passing parameters along with a multipart/form-data upload form (Java Http Post Upload)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536947/passing-parameters-along-with-a-multipart-form-data-upload-form-java-http-post/33751559#33751559)

I tried adding a hidden variable as well. But it does not seem to work with `ENCODING_MULTIPART`.

However I am concerned I have to pass multiple variables, is this method to go about the problem?

```
final FormPanel form = new FormPanel();
        form.setAction("./abc/sheets/importReport");
        form.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
        form.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
```

Is there any other method to pass parameters from the client to the server in the Http request?

Can anyone help me out?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: did you try just adding a hidden field to the FormPanel? http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Hidden.html

Comment: I tried this just now and its working, Though I have one doubt, I have a HorizontalPanel where in the upload buttons are. This HorizontalPanel is inside a verticalPanel which is inside the FormPanel(mentioned in the original question). If I add my hidden widget to the FormPanel it fails and if I add it to the Lowest panel with the upload buttons it works. Can you explain why is this happening? Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: FormPanel extends SimplePanel, so it can only wrap one widget. In your case the panel, so you need to add the hidden field to one of your panels

Comment: @MarcStröbel Thanks for your quick and apt reply!

Comment: @MarcStröbel If I use form encoding as ENCODING_MULTIPART. I cannot use the hidden variable method. Is there some workaround to use ENCODING_MULTIPART and not add the parameter in the url?

Comment: why can't you use ENCODING_MULTIPART? you will get 2 parts in your request, one for the file and one for your form data (hidden field). What's your server side build on?

Comment: Server is written in Java, I am using request.getParameter() to read the hidden value on the server-side.

Comment: look e.g. here how to handle multipart uploads : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet

Comment: Thanks a ton! :)